# What could cause IllegalStateException when running jar file?

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic

I have a jar file that runs fine on several different server instances, but on 2 servers a IllegalStateException is thrown in Thread-O.  Any ideas why this might be happening on 2 of our servers but works fine on many others? Compared hashes of jar files among different systems and they are identical.  Updated JVM and that resulted i no change.

```
java –jar patch-client.jar

Exception in thread “Thread-O” java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.PatchBundleTaget.<init>(PatchBundleTarget.jara:270)
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.PathTargetFactory.create(PatchTagetFactory:java:39) 
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.ProductAliasTarget.constructPatchTagetList(ProductAliasTarget.java:75)
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.ProductAliasTarget.<init>(ProductAliasTarget.java:47)
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.ProductAliasTargetHelper.getProdAliasTargetList(ProductAliasTargetHelper.java:54) 
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.ProductAliasTargetHelper.getAllHomeToProdAliasesTargetMap(ProductAliasTargetHelper.java:31)
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.ProductAliasTargetHelper.checkProfilesInProductAliases(ProductAliasTargetHelper.java:133) 
   at com.bea.plateng.patch.Patch$1.run(Patch.java:376)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

[IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) means the state of a component or configuration is incorrect.  I would look at the differences in configuration, not the code.

It is possible that there is a bug which triggers this error incorrectly, but I would start with the assumption, that the code is ok as it works on other machines.

Comment: I have the assumption that the code is ok, but I think somehow the JVM env is not correct.  I've installed a new VM instance hoping that would clear up the issue but it did not.  I agree with your assumption that there is something that is wrong in the configuration but where I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you get access to the code, or even break point it?  This will show you the condition which is failing which can be a good clue.